# How to set Line Break until the ActualHeight of RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

If the user clicks on my `RichEditBox` then the insertion pointer should appear at the beginning of the Line, not on the end of the string. For example, Let assume the `RichEditBox` can contain 5 lines for its `Height` so when the user clicks on the 3rd Line the insertion pointer should be at the beginning of 3rd Line not on the 1st Line. It is very hard to explain I hope you understand.

To achieve it I thought of setting Line Break until the end of `RichEditBox` by default.

**Solution Tried:**

I used below code to do it but It didn't work

```
var oldActualHeight = PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.ActualHeight;
while (PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.ActualHeight <= oldActualHeight)
{
    PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out string a);
    PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, a + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**My RichEditBox Code in XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RichEditBoxStyle" TargetType="RichEditBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <InkToolbar TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind PATH_INK_CANVAS}"/>
        <Button Name="ChangeButton" Content="Change" Click="ChangeButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <InkCanvas Name="PATH_INK_CANVAS" Canvas.ZIndex="-1"/>
            <RichEditBox Name="PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX" PlaceholderText="Input Text" Style="{StaticResource RichEditBoxStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such api that can get each line of  `RichEditBox`. So, if you want to move your cursor to the start of line. you can get the start position of line and focus it.

Above all, you should get start point of `RichEditBox` document.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ITextSelection selection = PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.Selection;
    selection.StartPosition = 0;
    selection.EndPosition = 0;
    originPoint = new Point();
    selection.GetPoint(HorizontalCharacterAlignment.Left, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, PointOptions.Start, out originPoint);  
}
```

They have same `X` about the point of each line start point. So you could get the line start point by current cursor position.

```
private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = new Point();
    ITextSelection selection = PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.Selection;

    var sta = selection.StartPosition;
    var en = selection.EndPosition;
    selection.GetPoint(HorizontalCharacterAlignment.Left, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, PointOptions.Start, out point);
    point = new Point(originPoint.X, point.Y);
    var pgformat = selection.ParagraphFormat;
    selection.SetPoint(point, PointOptions.Start, false);
    var start = selection.StartPosition;
    var end = selection.EndPosition;
    PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.Selection.SetRange(start, end + 1);
    PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
}
```

Please notice that the end position of the previous line with one blank space is same as the start position of the current line. So you should use one length range distinguish them.

```
PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX.Document.Selection.SetRange(start, end + 1);
```

Comment: Why do you put second code block in a `Button_Click` event?

Comment: When should I call the codes in the second code block?

Comment: When your cursor is in any position on a line.

Comment: It's not working. I called this code in PointerPressedEvent.

Comment: The above answer is simple sample for test, [It](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/UWPRichEditeBoxTest.git) could not apply to all the scenarios.

Comment: In your sample also It's not working. It just selects the first character of the last line. I think you have misunderstood my question. Take a look the code under Solution Tried. Shall I open an issue in your GitHub project to explain it more clearly?